# tabla sql con espacio en el nombre y los campos

Tags: sql-server, php7

Tengo la siguiente situación, me pidieron hacer un proyecto con una base de datos SQL ya creada pero me encuentro que los nombres de las tablas y los campos de las tablas están escritos con espacios y cuando trato de ejecutar mi consulta me envía un error de sintaxis. Esta base datos se encuentra funcionando con una aplicación hecha en Visual Basic y yo estoy haciendo una aplicación web con php. A continuación le dejo mi código:

```
Select Customer.AR Cust Password, Customer.AR Cust User Name FROM AR Customer AS Customer
```

**Error:**

> 19:04:05 Kernel error: [FreeTDS][MSSQL Server] , Server EC2AMAZ-977S99A\APPBSC, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'Password'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En SQL Server los delimitadores para los identificadores que se pueden utilizar son:

- Comillas Dobles
- Corchetes

[Delimitadores](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
Drop table if exists "mi tabla";
Create table "mi tabla" (id int);
go
Drop table if exists [mi tabla];
Create table [mi tabla] (id int);
go
```

Si bien aunque ambos son igual de válidos, las comillas dobles en determinadas ocasiones pueden ser no válidas.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
Drop table if exists "mi tabla";
Create table "mi tabla" (id int);
```

> Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 8 Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de
>   'mi tabla'.

```
GO
-- Opción válida
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
Drop table if exists [mi tabla];
Create table [mi tabla] (id int);
GO
```

> Los comandos se han completado correctamente.

[Set Quoted_Identifier](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

el interpretador de sql no distingue los campos y las columnas y que tiene espacios.. cuando llames estos debe ir sobre corchetes

```
select [Id],[Doc Number],[Internal Doc Number] 
from [TABLEA Con Espacio];
```

si los llamas asi:

```
select Id,Doc Number,Internal Doc Number from TABLEA Con Espacio
```

si necesitas renombra la columna para parsearla en un objeto lo puedes hacer asi

```
select [Id],[Doc Number] as Doc_Number
from [TABLEA Con Espacio];
```

el motor no sabe hasta donde estan columnas y las tablas

[Aqui puedes ver un ejemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e7f90/5)

en las ultima linea esta una consulta con error (sin corchetes)

espero que te sirva la informacion

Answer (score 0):

solo usa los backticks `` `nombre de tabla` ``  <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd>   ó   <kbd>}</kbd>  para obtenerlos